Where did the baseball term "lace" come from?
According to the baseball almanac, lace means:

To hit the ball hard. "In the second inning [Claude] Ritchey laced a single out in left field." (The New York Times, Apr. 28, 1908; Barry Popik).

I understand that the noun lace is made by twisting together fabric, which could explain the origin of the usage of lacing drugs.
But where did this baseball term come from?

Lacing drugs relates to decorative lace added later to fabric, not shoelacing it together. A laced drug has a potent extra amount in addition to the basic.

@YosefBaskin Good to know! Thanks

From: https://www.baseball-almanac.com
To hit the ball hard. "In the second inning [Claude] Ritchey laced a single out in left field." (The New York Times, Apr. 28, 1908; Barry Popik). "[Barry Bonds] promptly laced a pitch just over the fence." (The Baltimore Sun, Apr. 6, 2004). 1st Use. 1887. "Dolan went to bat in the eighth with a determined look in his eye, and in a few minutes was standing panting but happy, on third, having laced the ball out toward the fence in a way that was beautiful to behold." (Journal (Omaha), July 9; Ken Liss).

These days, I suspect some commentators are misunderstanding the phrase and interpreting it as "lase" via laser... Precise use of language is not one of the criteria for that job; colorful use of language is.

Zach, how can you not understand it?  there is no special meaning.  It's like saying thread the needle.  Lace the holes, lace the obstacles, lace ("twist and twine") through the correct path.  Also it has NOTHING to do with baseball, it's a completely normal English expression.  "The sailors laced the rocks" etc

Guys please see my answer for more on this

@Fattie it doesn't answer the OP's question. Your citations only support your idea, right or wrong, that to lace refers to the act of lacing footwear, in that a person moves in and out, or swerve opponents in a fast fashion. I don't think baseballs zig zag (such as laces (n) in a sport shoe) when they are hit by the batter. The trajectory of a ball follows a curve, but it can be thrown, kicked or hit hard.

Hi @Mari-LouA there are 20? examples in the answer of the phrase being used literally exactly that way (your expression above that lacing can only be used "literally" if there is "more than one lace-hole, darn it!" is the sort of extremism I usually agree with or exhibit :) ) But this is moot as the discussion is over as the comments are being deleted, best

@keshlam what an amazing observation!  100% agree!  Great "call" (pun) good one!!

The verb lace of the sense given in the OED as:

transitive. Sport (originally Baseball). To strike (a ball) forcefully; to hit (a run, pitch, etc.) in this way.

is a semantic extension from the earlier sense given in the OED as 'to lash (a person) with or as though with a whip or cord; to beat, thrash' which is first attested in 1599 per the OED. Both meanings (subsenses) are grouped under the same numbered sense. (sense 7)
For the etymology, OED says that this sense is:

apparently by association with lash v.1

The verb lash for the sense 'to beat, strike with a lash, whip, †rod, etc.' is from 1398 per OED. For the etymology, OED says that lash may have initially derived from an onomatopoeia.

An onomatopoeic origin is possible, and is favoured by the early appearance of the parallel and nearly synonymous lush v.1; compare dash, dush, flash, flush, mash, mush, smash, smush, etc.

Note: Your own source, Baseball Almanac, notes that the first use of the baseball term lace is from 1887, which is one year earlier than the first citation in the OED, listed as 1888. Here is the citation from 1888 from the OED:

Richard Johnston pulled himself together and laced the ball down to the farthest corner of the centrefield. 
Boston Daily Globe 12 June 5/2


I don't have access to OED, but "lash" turning into "lace" feels a bit... interesting. If it came up specifically in the context of baseball, wouldn't a simple synecdoche be at least as plausible (baseballs somewhat famously have laces)? Do they address that at all?

Aren't baseball stitched up with red 'laces'? Might that work its way into this conversation?

No connection to "laces" (of a baseball) mentioned in the OED. I haven't found in my searches also.

Bonus: The verb drive has the same or a very similar sense in sports terminology (which is originally a cricket term): "If you drive a ball, such as in golf, cricket, baseball, or football, you hit or kick it hard so that it travels a long way:" - Collins. The etymology of the term drive can be explained with semantic extension and sense development as well.

One of the standard meanings of lace as a verb is "to hit hard." Here is the relevant definition in Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003):

lace vt ... 5 BEAT, LASH

Paul Dickson, The Dickson Baseball Dictionary (1989) reports that the term has appeared in the context of baseball since the late nineteenth century:

lace/lace one v. To hit the ball hard. 1st [cited occurrence] 1888. "Lace it out." (caption used in Thomas W. Lawson's The Krank)

Although Google Books does find a copy of Lawson's book, whose full title is The Krank: His Language and What It Means, it isn't searchable (despite its being 136 years old and, therefore, presumably, out of copyright). One source refers to this volume as "baseball's rarest book"; and as its title suggests, before fans came into popular usage, the slang term for baseball enthusiasts—at least in Boston—was kranks. In any case, I can't find a viewable copy of the original picture that illustrates someone "lacing it out."
The two earliest matches in the Library of Congress's Chronicling America newspaper database for the verb lace in the context of baseball are from 1888. From "They Played Ball: Giants Won To-Day's Game from Indianapolis," in the New York Evening World (May 8, 1888):

Ward was sent to first on balls. Ewing went out on a foul tip. Ward went to third on Connor's safe drive over second, Connor getting to second on Denny's muff of the throw in. Slattery laced the ball over short for a base, bringing Ward home. On [Indianapolis catcher] Buckley's throw down to catch Slattery at second Connor scored[.] Slattery, was caught between second and third and run out. Two runs.

And from "Ah, Our Giants! Chicago Handsomely Defeated in the First Game," in the New York Evening World (May 10, 1888):

Pfeffer sent a hot grounder to Richardson and was retired at first. Big Ed Williamson was sent to first on balls. Burns laced a hot grounder to Richardson, who fumbled and threw to Ward, who muffed, Williamson landing safely at second and Burns on first.

It seems quite likely that these two instances, published two days apart in the same New York newspaper, were written by the same uncredited sportswriter. I didn't find any instances in Chronicling America search results that mention hitting a baseball "on the laces." If that phrase is the source of the idea of a batter "lacing" a baseball, it has yet to be substantiated by examples in print from 1888 or before.
As for the alternative argument, proposed in an answer by Fattie, that laced indicates something akin to "guided successfully through a series of twists and turns"—a meaning that would make perfect sense in describing someone weaving the ball through traffic on a British football pitch—it is not hard to find examples where laced is used in the context of home runs, which involve no weaving at all.
For example, from Bill Baer, 100 Things Phillies Fans Should Know & Do Before They Die (2012):

Thinking [Randy] Wolf would be taking again [with a count of three balls and no strikes], [Adam] Bernero grooved a batting practice fastball over the plate. Who could fault him? Ninety-nine percent of pitchers would be looking for a walk there. Wolf, representing the 1 percent, whipped the bat around and laced the ball over the right-field stands for his second home run of the game and the fourth of his career. The Phillies were up 9–4 and would go on to tack on six more runs for an easy 15–4 rout of the Rockies.

And from David Benham & Jason Benham, Miracle in Shreveport: A Memoir of Baseball, Fatherhood, and the Stadium That Launched a Dream (2018):

I know it's a crazy dream, but that is what I felt like at the plate. God's presence was so powerful when I was in the box that often after I laced the ball over the fence or delivered one of my many game-winning hits that year, I retreated behind the dugout to pray—and cry. I couldn't help it.

And from Ken LaZebnik, Buzzie and the Bull: A GM, a Clubhouse Favorite, and the Dodgers' 1965 Championship Season (2020):

The stadium clock showed that it was almost midnight when Lou Johnson came to bat. Red reliever Joey Jay threw, and Johnson laced the ball into the left field pavilion for a walk-off homer. The Dodgers had done it. They were now in first place.


MW is wrong, or, it's a "coincidental use".

"Burns laced a hot grounder to Richardson" it's incredibly obvious the writer meant laced as in laced.  ie, a similar thought to "threaded the needle". (Obviously, a baseball generally physically goes in a straight line; unlike talking about (say) a running back in football who laces his way past a few opponents, but metaphorically it's like Burns snuck the ball past the relevant obstacles.)

if you have a minute pls. notice my edited answer and give me your thoughts. This question, and the dictionary entries, are mystifying to me.

I don't have any sources to prove it, but my understanding has always been that it is the shortening of a longer superlative statement "he knocked the ball right out of the laces" (alternately "he knocked the cover off the ball") which implies a force so hard that the laces holding the leather cover on are ripped apart, and only the inner core of the ball is launched.

This was my intuition but it also seems like a little bit of a stretch, perhaps as something that is interpreted after it's already being used

I agree that this has always seemed like a related thought.  Also confusingly football kickers - say - are always talking about laces.  However the plain obvious fact is that "laces" has a simple literal meaning (simply look at my answer - or just google for a million examples) and it's extremely confusing (to me) to try to find the "origin of the idiom" since it's .. literal :O

(Just more idle thoughts.) If it originated with an intended meaning like "knocked the laces off" or "knocked it out of its laces," then perhaps instead of looking for the earliest use of "laced," perhaps it would be fruitful to look for an earlier use of something like "he absolutely de-laced it" or "he unlaced that ball." Someone shortening it from "he unlaced it" to "he laced it" strikes me as similar to the evolution of "i couldn't care less" to "i could care less." Or perhaps like "he de-brained me" to "he brained me."

I'm mystified by this question and the answers, and I'm mystified by the M-W definition.
To "lace" a situation means ... to lace it.
It can't really be defined any more than that; put a lace (say!) through a series of holes in which it belongs.
Either literally (with - say! - a lace) or literally with another object or of course metaphorically (as in politics, etc).
ie, you guided something (literally or metaphorically) successfully through a series of twists and turns.
It's very similar to saying "thread the needle". (Thread the needle, ie you "guided a largish object through a small hole".)
Obviously, it's hard to google many terms due to clutter (eg, the laces on footballs, skinhead slang, etc), but
If you simply google, say, "laced his way..." you will find innumerable examples.
There are innumerable both literal and metaphorical examples.

Taishi NARIKUNI laced his way to the 70kg world title ...


Cody Goodwin laced his way to a 10-0 technical fall, which is also a freestyle rule


Assylzhan Yessengeldi laced his way to the 61kg finals


He power laced his way to 3 points


My giant Maine Coon cat, King, laced his way through the legs of my lounge chair


lead guitarist Michael Wilton laced his way in and out of the spinning and howling guitar licks that augment the track's


Taylor laced his way to 40 off 32 balls, an innings that included five fours and two big sixes


The tall man laced his way through every couple on the dance floor

If you add almost any field of endeavour to the search (try words like horse, golf, sailing, politics, cars, child-rearing, cabbage, marriage, trees ... etc, etc, etc) you'll get innumerable examples.

Gonnella started fifth and methodically laced his way to third on lap eight


laced his way in and out of the stream of vehicles


Mr. Herriott held the reins of his spirited horses, and brought them down to a steady, rapid trot. It was a cold but sunny day in February, and as he laced his way in and out of the stream of vehicles...


His hands carefully laced his way through his bloodstained feathers


laced his way through the Yeomen forward wall for one long gain after another Quarterback Rich Poling added to the Crimsons defensive frustrations


Swooper ducked and laced his way through the net, knowing better than Anna what would happen if they touched one of its jagged strands of light


Bruntil, down 1-0, created her angle to an attack and laced her way to a tech

Metaphorical uses ...

the same Brad has laced his way throughout the teenage movie universe


Sarah HILDEBRANDT laced her way to a second world final.


source, a Google.com search


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
